# Tests with null hypothesis of dependence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, conditional-independence

Let's say I have a set of variables $\mathbf{V}$ and I want to study conditional dependence between two of them $A, B\in \mathbf{V}$ by conditioning on a set $\mathbf{Z}\subseteq\mathbf{V}$. In other words, I want to study if they are independent ($A\perp B|\mathbf{Z}$) or dependent ($A\not\perp B|\mathbf{Z}$)

One technique to do this is to perform an independence test that assumes variable independence as the null hypothesis and, by rejecting it, you accept the alternative hypothesis $A\not\perp B|\mathbf{Z}$.

Are there tests that do the opposite by having as null hypothesis the *dependence* between $A$ and $B$ so then rejecting it would imply to $A\perp B|\mathbf{Z}$ ? If so, do they require particular assumptions on the type of dependency? Any pointer to such techniques would be really appreciated

Comment: You might be interested in [equivalence testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test). The TOST discussed on that page makes intuitive sense to me.

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the comment! I had a look at them but in my case study I'm not able to specify thresholds for which an effect is considered as interesting, that is I'm not able to set thresholds for writing the null hypotheses

Comment: Some of the trouble with trying to prove independence is that you could have a population-level dependence of $0.00000000000001$, which is unlikely to have practical significance…but it is not zero. Given enough observations, your inferential procedures start to pick up on that tiny amount of dependence. (I’m thinking of mutual information, though not there are other measures of dependence.)